# Read HKEY_USERS and HKEY_CURRENT_USERS

Tags: powershell, registry

```
$strIPAddrTmp = "172.28.27.200"
$strKeyIEConnections = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections\"
$strRegType = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::CurrentUser
$strRegKey  = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($strRegType, $strIPAddrTmp)
$strRegKey  = $strRegKey.OpenSubKey($strKeyIEConnections)
```

I used the PS script above to try to read the contents of:

```
HKCU::Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections\DefaultConnectionSettings
```

I was just trying to check the IE proxy settings of a target remote machine.
I found out that the script always returns the contents from `HKEY_USERS` instead of `HKEY_CURRENT_USERS`.
What did I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be the answer!

1) Find out the SID of the user logged onto the machine.

```
$strSID = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount  -Filter "Domain = '$domain' AND Name = '$name'").SID
```

2) Use the SID to find out the info in HKEY_USER:

```
$strKeyIEConnections = "$strSID\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections\"
$strRegType = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::Users
$strRegKey  = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($strRegType, $strIPAddrTmp)
$strRegKey  = $strRegKey.OpenSubKey($strKeyIEConnections)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot connect to the current user hive remotely. You can if you know the user's sid and connect to it via the HKEY_USERS hive.

Answer (score 1):

The subkeys of `HKEY_USERS` are the places where the user registry hives (`ntuser.dat` from their profiles) are actually mounted after a user logs in. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is just an alias for `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-...`, where `S-1-5-...` is the SID of the currently logged-in user.